# Scraping through recursive functions decrease scrapy concurrent requests to 1

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a large web-scraping project in Scrapy. It works very well, but after running for some time it slows down gradually until it makes 1 request at the time. It scrapes projects details and messages between users in that project (There are many projects).

I have a function that scrapes messages, 1 call returns 25 messages and at some points there are over 50K messages so I recursively call the same function until all messages are scraped like the following pseudocode:

```
Get project details
Get messages page#1
If hasMoreMessages:
    Get messages page#2
    If hasMoreMessages:
         Get messages page#3
         If hasMoreMessages
             Get messages page#4
             .....
```

I assume that this is the cause of my issue, isn't it? If so, what would you do if you faced this problem?

I tried to find a setting for restricting 1 concurrent request per project instead of all my concurrent requests waiting for 1 response.

My thoughts might be wrong, that's why I am posting this question. I am hopeful to find a solution. Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what your code is doing. But scrapy works in different way - it doesn't run directly next requests but it `yield Request` and it puts it at the end of special list - and later other code (engine) gets request from list and send to server (using another thread/process).

Comment: I am sorry I was unclear about my code but your reply was very helpful, that's what I wanted to know. I imagined that it works like if I make a request to a function (with yield), then make another request from that function, then the first request will be waiting for the second request to finish. But you solved my confusion. Really appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: BTW: you can see image (and description) which shows how scrapy works [Architecture overview](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)